# AWS Glue ETL Job triggered on batches of S3 Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, etl, aws-glue

I have an S3 bucket that gets many files dropped in it (1000 records/min). I want to trigger a Glue ETL job on batches of these dropped files.

I have looked at using Firehose to aggregate the batches of the events, but that requires a lot of chained resources. Like S3 -> Lambda -> Firehose -> ...

What is the best way to process my data in batches?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Glue Job Triggers which will allow you to run the glue job at scheduled intervals, rather than as an S3 event trigger?

Are you processing streaming data?  Don't see a use case / purpose for Firehose, with your limited information.

Comment: Firehose has a small batch size for our application if we pass the actual data. The records we are passing are just pointers to the files in S3, but we need to process those files in large batches.